Ubuntu 22.04 nic Broadcom driver is not compatible with the kernel versions
When upgrading the kernel version of Ubuntu 22.04 from 5.15.0-122-generic to 6.8.0-45-generic, a phenomenon occurred where the nic Broadcom interface could not be found, so the Ubuntu nic Broadcom driver was not compatible with the kernel versions. I would like to know about this and how to install Broadcom drivers.
